# How set maximum length of message for Autobahn Websocket?

Tags: java, android, python, websocket, autobahn

I use "[Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/)" on android (Java) as client and on linux as server (python). When I send big messages from client we have disconnetion. That's because of exceeding of max message length. For different devices this limit is different too. For "Minix Neo X8" is 2Mb and for "HTC One" is 8Mb. What is the problem? How can I set max length message by force?

```
import de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection;
import de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketException;
import de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketHandler;
import de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketOptions;


WebSocketManager mWebSocketManager = new WebSocketManager();
    MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler();

    private final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();

        private void createSocket() {
            try {
                mConnection.connect("ws://192.168.45.86:1488/echo", mWebSocketManager);
            } catch (WebSocketException e) {

                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }

    private class WebSocketManager extends WebSocketHandler {
            @Override
            public void onTextMessage(String data) {
                try {
                    messageHandler.parseMessage(data);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
                Log.d("RECD", "Connection established");
                messageHandler.sendMessage("Request", "Login", 16, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
            }
        }
```

I try use **setMaxMessagePayloadSize** for setting maximum length of message (in in octets):

```
private void createSocket() {
        try {
            WebSocketOptions options = new WebSocketOptions();
            options.setMaxMessagePayloadSize(33554432);
            mConnection.connect("ws://192.168.45.86:1488/echo", mWebSocketManager , options);

        } catch (WebSocketException e) {

            Log.d("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

but it does not affect the length of the message. If not use **setMaxMessagePayloadSize**, then I get an exception, when the message exceeds 65536 bytes:

> W/System.err﹕ de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketException: message payload
>   exceeds payload limit

The document states that the default length of message is  4 mb.

http://autobahn.ws/android/_gen/de/tavendo/autobah/WebSocketOptions.html#setmaxmessagepayloadsize